# Does the component-type name needs to be unique for custom components?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, custom-component

I am new to **Custom components** topic starting with JSF 2.2

However, I am first considering the case with `JSF2.0`

Consider the snippet:

```
@FacesComponent(value = "components.WelcomeComponent1", createTag = true)
public class WelcomeComponent extends UIComponentBase {

}
```

Do notice `value = "components.WelcomeComponent1"`

referencing it in the UI wireframe-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:t="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/component">
    <h:head>
        <title></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>       
        <t:welcomeComponent value="Welcome" to="Rafael Nadal"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Consider the second case with the **same name** of the class as in first case but in a **different package** with a different **component-type name**:

```
@FacesComponent("components.WelcomeComponent")
public class WelcomeComponent extends UIComponentBase {
          // code goes here
}
```

Do notice the `"components.WelcomeComponent"`

**taglib.xml** in **WEB_INF**

```
    <namespace>http://atp.welcome.org/welcome</namespace>

    <tag>
        <tag-name>welcome</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>components.WelcomeComponent</component-type>
        </component>

        <attribute>
            <name>id</name>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
            <description>Component id</description>
            <required>false</required>
        </attribute>


    </tag>

</facelet-taglib>
```

and referencing the latter -

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:t="http://atp.welcome.org/welcome">
    <h:head>
        <title></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <t:welcome value="Welcome" to=""/>        
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Both of the above examples are part of the same web app & work fine.
However if I change the component-type name in the second case to make it the same as in first case,

```
@FacesComponent("components.WelcomeComponent1")
```

I do get-

> Warning: This page calls for XML namespace
>   http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/component declared with prefix t but no
>   taglibrary exists for that namespace

Clearly the entry/tag declared in `taglib.xml` is preferred.

So, the **component-type name** needs to be **unique** in each case. Right?

I know it very well that the namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/component` was introduced with `JSF2.2`.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **yes**, it should be unique. JSF thinks of it as a name for your custom component (in the similar way as a `@ManagedBean`). Basically, component-type allows `Application` instance to create new instances of `UIComponent` subclasses (your and every other custom component) by using defined component-type and `createComponent()` method.